# PHP command line script to rename a folder without entering current folder name as an arg?

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I'm now wondering if it's even possible, but I'd like to have the following functionality:

User calls

> `php scriptName --setAppName [new name]`

on the command line and as a result, a directory is renamed.

To begin with, the default name of the folder will be 'App Name'. I obviously do not want to hard code this because once changed I want to retain the functionality of the script.

So is there a way for this to work without me having to have to resort to

> `php scriptName --setAppName [oldFolderName] [NewFolderName]`

The reason I'm using PHP and not bash is because I'd rather not make the user add my script(s) to their PATH to run them easily. If there's a solution I'm missing that would involve bash script and not require that I'm all ears too.

A quick working script (that works with the first default folder name):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

$app_name = 'App\ Name/';

if ($argc < 3) {
    print "Usage: php boiler --rename [new app name]";
    exit();
}

$new_app_name = $argv[2];

$command = "mv '".$app_name."' '".$new_app_name."'";

exec($command);

echo "App folder renamed to ". $new_app_name;
exit;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your app has something that can be used to tell it apart from other files (perhaps an autoloader script with an unique comment at the top) you could make your script scan each directory recursively until it finds that file and then acts on the directory that contains it.

Comment: If the current app name cannot be determined with satisfactory certainty (e.g. by snooping around the contents of the current directory) then obviously you have to record it somewhere (e.g. in a file whose name is fixed).

Comment: So perhaps the best way is to go with a config.php file and set the name in there, which will then be changed every time this script is run and will help determine the folder name?

Comment: @KMountford Right.  Put a file called 'appname.txt' in the folder.  Have the contents of that file be CURRENTFOLDERNAME and then just edit it on the folder rename to 'My new folder name'

Comment: Why not use Bash and move the script to `/usr/local/bin`? All users will be able to use it without further action.